# WFS GetFeature with cql_filter=Intersects not working for cascaded layers

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, getfeature

I have a cascaded (WFS store) layer in my GeoServer. I want to download the data of the layer in Excel format for a provided polygon. In a normal scenario I export the data as below:

```
https://my-geoserver/workspace/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=layerName&outputFormat=excel2007&CQL_FILTER=intersects(GEOM,POLYGON((140622.7275518125 158136.306018296,140676.74283158602 158165.31859678068,140714.0110057701 158091.48983712035,140661.41098439335 158063.18487973593,140622.7275518125 158136.306018296)))
```

But in case of the cascaded layer the above is not working, an empty Excel spreadsheet is being downloaded. I tried OGC filter as well, but same result.

ge

I know I can achieve this by using BBOX but I cannot use BBOX for intersecting as the intersecting needs to be a polygon for filtering purpose of the layer I'm trying to export.

Cascaded layer: I have created a WFS store in my GeoServer and exposing the layer.

Comment: what does the log file show? You might need to turn up the debug level

Comment: @IanTurton There is no error in the logs. Request: getFeature
    service = wfs
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = https://my-geoserver/ 
    query[0]:
        filter = [ GEOM intersects POLYGON ((140622.7275518125 158136.306018296, 140676.74283158602 158165.31859678068, 140714.0110057701 158091.48983712035, 140661.41098439335 158063.18487973593, 140622.7275518125 158136.306018296)) ]
        typeName[0] = LayerName 
    outputFormat = excel2007
    resultType = results

Comment: I would replace intersects with disjoint, its' converse function.  I would also try a different output format that is native to geoserver.  Excel, as discussed here, https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/excel.html#excel-extension, is an extension.  Do you get a blank excel file using disjoint?  Does the intersection return anything when you use a different output format?

Comment: what is the native SRS of the layer? does it match your query polygon? - try turning the logging level up to GeoTools debug, you will see a lot more information then